# SQL Auction create winner list from info in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am new and learning MYSQL as i go. i have an auction site that i am trying to pull the info from 3 different spots in mysql db.  i am trying to make a winners list.  In the bid_log  i need to get the title from bid_auction from the id. 
The winner name from userid and accept that had the number 1 . 1 is the person who won the auction. I also need the bid price of the winning auction. I am not sure if this can be done but is it possible to group the winner 
by id if they have won more then 1 item in the auction ? Thank you for the help.

bid_log

```
auction_id     userid    initial_bid    bid_price    accept     modified
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 190           770        10.00          10.00          0      2014-01-23 16:33:19
 190           771        15.00          15.00          1      2014-01-23 16:33:35
 191           770        10.00          10.00          0      2014-01-23 17:51:55
 191           753        15.00          15.00          1      2014-01-23 17:52:17
 217           753        5.00           5.00           0      2014-01-24 22:56:49
 217           770        7.00           7.00           1      2014-01-24 22:57:06
```

bid_auctions

```
 id     title
 -------------------------
     190    Gold Picture Frame
     191    Gift Basket
     217    Gift Card
```

users

```
 id     name
 ----------------
     770    John Smith
     753    Jane Smith
     771    Bruce Wayne
```

What i would like the following results to look like

Winners

```
 name            title                bid_price
---------------------------------------------------
Bruce Wayne    Gold Picture Frame      15.00
Jane Smith     Gift Basket             15.00
John Smith     Gift Card               7.00
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT a.auction_id, b.userid, c.bid_price d.accept
FROM bid_log a
  CROSS JOIN bid_auctions b
  LEFT JOIN users c
ON a.userID = c.name AND
  b.ID = c.title
ORDER BY a.Name, b.title
```

I dont know how to get it to select only accept that has a 1

Thanks to Strawberry i have a working SQL
Here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b135b/1/0) showing it works.

I am just gettting a blank page, i have a problem with my php displaying the query.

here is my php code i am using.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($link))
{
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT u.name
   , i.title
   , x.bid_price 
   FROM sto8v_bid_log x 
   JOIN sto8v_bid_users u 
   ON u.userid = x.userid 
   JOIN sto8v_bid_auctions i 
   ON i.id = x.id 
   WHERE x.accept = 1;";
   $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql); //this line executes query

// error checking
if (!$result){
    printf("Error: %s\n%s\n", mysqli_sqlstate($link),mysqli_error($link));
}

// 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo "" . $row['winner'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not sure that this can be done? If this couldn't be done, the internet would collapse! Tell us a little about the `accept` column - and why there's both an `initial bit` and a `bid_price` column.

Comment: the initial bid column is used for buy it now price it also fills with the current bid price.

Comment: ok. This is very, very easy. So can we see your best effort. :-)

Comment: I have added what i have tried.  i can still not figure out how to only select auction with 1 in the accept row.

Comment: Maybe you don't have a column called `item`. My schema differs from yours!

Comment: I edit your code a bit i have update it to work with my db columns and row names. it work perfect in SQL Fiddle. so i know my schema works because it from your code that also works. i just changed some names.

Comment: Clearly, your real schema differs from mine in at least one respect; i.e. `sto8v_bid_auctions` DOES NOT have a column called `item`!

Comment: The error message no longer corresponds to the query

Comment: i no longer get an error message i just get a blank page. I just need to figure out my php to show the query.

Comment: ? but you have no column/alias called `winner`!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bid_log;

CREATE TABLE bid_log
(item_id INT NOT NULL  
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,initial_bid DECIMAL(5,2)  
,bid_price DECIMAL(5,2)    
,accept TINYINT     
,modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO bid_log VALUES
( 190           ,770        ,10.00          ,10.00          ,0      ,'2014-01-23 16:33:19'),
( 190           ,771,        15.00,          15.00      ,    1      ,'2014-01-23 16:33:35'),
(191           ,770 ,       10.00 ,         10.00       ,   0      ,'2014-01-23 17:51:55'),
(191          , 753 ,       15.00 ,         15.00       ,   1      ,'2014-01-23 17:52:17'),
(217         ,  753 ,       5.00  ,         5.00        ,   0      ,'2014-01-24 22:56:49'),
(217         ,  770 ,       7.00  ,         7.00        ,   1      ,'2014-01-24 22:57:06');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items;

CREATE TABLE items
(item_id     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,item VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO items VALUES
(190    ,'Gold Picture Frame'),
(191    ,'Gift Basket'),
(217    ,'Gift Card');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users
(user_id INT NOT NULL     ,name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO users VALUES (770    ,'John Smith'),(753,'Jane Smith'),(771    ,'Bruce Wayne');

  SELECT u.name
       , i.item
       , x.bid_price 
    FROM bid_log x 
    JOIN users u 
      ON u.user_id = x.user_id 
    JOIN items i 
      ON i.item_id = x.item_id 
   WHERE x.accept = 1;
  +-------------+--------------------+-----------+
  | name        | item               | bid_price |
  +-------------+--------------------+-----------+
  | Bruce Wayne | Gold Picture Frame |     15.00 |
  | Jane Smith  | Gift Basket        |     15.00 |
  | John Smith  | Gift Card          |      7.00 |
  +-------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

See... easy :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a lot easier then i thought. It works for me. i am getting an error in my php file. i edit my work to show what i have done.